# Events for video time update not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to send events in a video time update but it is firing the events at the same time instead of when it reaches 25%, 50% & 75%

this is the code im using i found it online and i cannot get it to work

```
function init() {
  videoId.addEventListener('ended', videoEnd, false)
  videoId.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdate, false)
  videoId.addEventListener('play', videoPlay, false)
  videoId.addEventListener('pause', videoPause, false)
}

function setKeyFrames(duration) {
  var quarter = (duration / 4).toFixed(1)
  sessionStorage.setItem('one', quarter)
  sessionStorage.setItem('two', (quarter * 2).toFixed(1))
  sessionStorage.setItem('three', (quarter * 3).toFixed(1))
}

function videoTimeUpdate() {
  var curTime = videoId.currentTime.toFixed(1);
  var videoTitle = $(this).attr('data-description');
  switch (curTime) {
  case sessionStorage.getItem('one'):
  console.log("25%");
    ga('send', 'event', 'video', '25% video played', videoTitle)
    sessionStorage.setItem('one', null)
  case sessionStorage.getItem('two'):
  console.log("50%");
    ga('send', 'event', 'video', '50% video played', videoTitle)
    sessionStorage.setItem('two', null)
   case sessionStorage.getItem('three'):
  console.log("75%");
    ga('send', 'event', 'video', '75% video played', videoTitle)
    sessionStorage.setItem('three', null)
  }
}
```

any help would be appreciated